# version sdk 32 com.android.support:appcompat

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sdk

I need to change sdk 28 to sdk 32 but this library is discontinued

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7
```

And

```
com.android.support:design
```

Which is the new version? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should migrate to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx), thats official `com.android.support` packages successor. check out doc [how to migrate](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) and some introducing blog [post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html)